# Is JBI dead ? Is it still a valid criteria in an ESB selection?

Tags: soa, esb, servicebus, jbi

JBI standard is (was?) supposed to be the standard for Entreprise Service Bus, especially in terms of facility of reuse/exchange of capabilities of different ESBs (or lonely Service Engine providers)

Known JBI implementations are (according to wikipedia) :

- OpenESB => JBI + OSGI (since Oracle bought Sun it is now community only)
- Petals
- ServiceMix => The last (4) release is based on OSGI (but remains compatible with JBI)
- Fuse => According to Guillaume Nodet JBI 1.0 and 2.0 are dead http://servicemix.396122.n5.nabble.com/DISCUSS-ServiceMix-future-td3212177.html Last fuse webcast regarding WS-Security were using CXF-Osgi
- Mule => According to Ross Mason, JBI 1.0 is dead http://www.infoq.com/news/2008/05/jbi-debate
- Oracle => Supposed to be JBI ? Definitively follows SCA
- TIBCO => Supposed to be JBI ? Definitively follows SCA

Non implementers:

- IBM => as far as I know is not JBI. Definitively follows SCA
- JBoss => Custom

Without taking into consideration that JBI works, and that it address different problems than SCA, would you really took into account in an ESB choice the fact that it is or not JBI compliant ? or stick to the capabilities of the ESB ?

Reference: [What are the differences / similarities between JBI and SCA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268370/what-are-the-differences-similarities-between-jbi-and-sca)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah jbi is dying. There is not gonna be a jbi 2 spec. Check out the blog post by gnodet, lead on jbi and servicemix, posted on his blog, about his thoughts on jbi.

Its just so so much easier to do apache camel, or spring integration than jbi.

Comment: Here is the link: http://gnodet.blogspot.com/2010/12/thoughts-about-servicemix.html

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to JBI seems to be more than one... Apache Camel or Spring Integration as mentioned by Clause.. which means, JBI need exists as standard.. to avoid multiple ways of doing the same thing..

I think JBI would continue to evolve as it is just a specification and not implementation.. Camel and Spring could comply to such specification

More can be read at 
http://www.pymma.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=127:is-jbi-dead-not-of-course&catid=82:blog-paul-perez&Itemid=574

Raja Nagendra Kumar,
C.T.O
www.tejasoft.com